# How to see these event parameters for all time in Firebase?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

**Platform**: Unity

**Plugin version**: 10.05.0

When sending logs from `Firebase` via overload

```cs
FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("hero_level_up", "hero_one", 25);

FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("hero_level_up", "hero_two", 25);
```

And in this case, I can track events by name, but I can’t track them by the parameters of this event, for the entire time, instead, in the Dashboard, I see Realtime data for the last 30 minutes.

In the screenshot, you can see the `hero_level_up` event, which does not have event calls in runtime, but was actually called, and exactly passed the parameters.

**QUESTION**: How to see these parameters for all time?

[image: 1]